# Swing Menu dimensions

Tags: java, swing, menu

Greetings. I am trying to learn Java and Swing (today is my first day).

I have been able to set up a menu in my test application. but the items occupy very little space (they are narrow). How do I go about extendng the amount of space it uses?

[Screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?087aa4c9dc.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?087aa4c9dc.jpg)

I am studying *Teach Yourself Java 6 in 21 Days 5th Ed*, Java Swing, 2nd Edition, 2002 and Teach Yourself Programming With Java In 24 Hours, 4th Edition (2005) but none of them shed any light on this issue.

**EDIT:**

Menu code:

```
    JMenu _Game = new JMenu("Game");

    JMenuItem _New = new JMenuItem("New");

    JMenuItem _Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    JMenu _Turn = new JMenu("Turn");

    JMenuItem _Red = new JMenuItem("Red");
    JMenuItem _Yellow = new JMenuItem("Yellow");

    _Turn.add(_Red);
    _Turn.add(_Yellow);

    _Game.add(_New);
    _Game.addSeparator();
    _Game.add(_Turn);
    _Game.addSeparator();
    _Game.add(_Exit);

    JMenu _Help = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem _About = new JMenuItem("About");
    _Help.add(_About);


    JMenuBar _MenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    _MenuBar.add(_Game);
    _MenuBar.add(_Help);

    setJMenuBar(_MenuBar);
```

EDIT: Solved!

```
JMenuItem _New = new JMenuItem("New        ");
```

just add spaces as needed! simple.

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Java is not an acronym. Java is not an acronym. Java is not an acronym. Java is not an acronym. Java is not an acronym.

Comment: @Dave Jarvis: Menu dimensions for a game? what does that mean?

Comment: As you are learning I should mention that the convention for Java is to start variable names with a lower case letter, like this: JMenu gameMenu = new JMenu("Game"); Also the ugly underscore first convention is not popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Solved!

```
JMenuItem _New = new JMenuItem("New        ");
```

just add spaces as needed! simple.

this is a hack and not a pretty one but havent come across others yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the menu width is automatically adjusted to the width of the longest text. Why would you want the menu to be wider than necessary?

If you must, you should be able to use [`setMinimumSize()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize(java.awt.Dimension)) to force a minimum width.

Comment: or for that matter, why should DOS ever need more than 640k of memory

Comment: I dont want to use numbers to achive this. i am looking for a layout solution.

Comment: Why would you want the menu to be wider than necessary: if you look at windows all menu items have space around them. makes it look nicer.

Comment: @Zak: that comparison makes more sense whatsoever. Letting the width auto-adjust does not impose a restriction on how wide it can get when necessary.

Comment: @ikurtz: if you look at windows, most menus have more entires, some of which are longer, thus the auto-adjusted width is larger. But the actual space before and after the longest entry is only slightly larger than in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Menus as such looks good anyway. But if *really* need to have a hack, here it is
Get ready for some real quick n dirty hack.

```
private static final SPACES="   ";
JMenu _Game = new JMenu(SPACES + "Game" + SPACES);
JMenuItem _New = new JMenuItem(SPACES + "New" + SPACES);
JMenuItem _Exit = new JMenuItem(SPACES + "Exit" + SPACES);
JMenu _Turn = new JMenu(SPACES + "Turn" + SPACES);
JMenuItem _Red = new JMenuItem(SPACES + "Red" + SPACES);
JMenuItem _Yellow = new JMenuItem(SPACES + "Yellow" + SPACES);
```